# Обновление и удаление по номеру строки в таблице

Tags: postgresql

Как можно обновить или удалить запись по её порядковому номеру в таблице?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под **порядковым номером**? Результат функции `row_number()`? Или поле типа `serial`?

Comment: Ну все записи в таблице записаны по порядку. Первичного ключа может не быть. Посмотрел row_number, годиться в общем-то, только непонятно как им воспользоваться в where инструкции update, пишет "window functions are not allowed in WHERE"

Comment: Помоему вы делаете что то не верно.
Что значит порядковый номер ?
А если мы сортировку поменяем, "порядковый номер" укажет уже на другую строку, какую же тогда нуно апдейтить ?
Не уверен, но думаю что можно поигратся с:

update table set field=<value> LIMIT 10, 1

т.е теоретически должно обновить 10ю строчку.

Comment: Теоретически update table set field=<value> LIMIT 10 должен обновить первые попавшиеся 10 строк. На практике этот код не отработает, ибо в синтаксисе update нет limit

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать object identifiers (OIDs) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-oid.html

```
CREATE TABLE test (value text) WITH oids;

SELECT oid, value FROM test;

UPDATE test SET value='2' WHERE oid=1;
```

Comment: Если он есть, то данный вариант отлично подойдет

Answer (score 1):

Обновить:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name='value' WHERE row_id=<your_value>
```

Удалить:
    DELETE FROM table_name WHERE row_id=<your_value>

Где:

- **table_name** - имя таблицы, в которой производим действия
- **column_name** - столбец, который обновляем
- **row_id** - подразумевает id строки, над которой вы производите действия.
     Например, если у вас есть в таблице
     столбец id, его смело можно
     использовать здесь
- **your_value** - значение, по которому вы осуществляете поиск
     строки для обновления или удаления.

Comment: Первичного ключа в таблице может не быть

Answer (score 1):

Нет такого понятия, как порядковый номер записи в таблице

Для апдейта конкретной записи необходимо ее выделить по уникальным признакам.

Если есть первычный ключ, то логичнее использовать его.
Если его нет, то как уже упоминалось в ответе Alexey Slynko, можно воспользоваться уникальным системным идентификатором строки, oid, опять таки, если он есть. Ну а если нет ни того, ни другого, то только по уникальной комбинации полей записи, например, так

```
update test set field_1 = value where (field_1, field_2, field_3) = (value_1, value_2, value_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

id должен присутствовать в любом случае

```
UPDATE table_name 
    SET field_name = field_value 
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id FROM table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET record_number
);
```

Comment: С чего это он должен быть? Совсем не обязательно

Comment: Для реализации отношений много-ко-многим - да. В остальных случаях я не вижу ни одной причины не использовать автоинкрементные ключи для создания PRIMARY KEY. Если я не прав и вам нечем заняться - переубедите меня.
GUID'ы вроде как уникальны, но зачем? Тем более, что, например, в Windows нельзя использовать их как первичные ключи, т.к. генератор не гарантирует уникальность, об этом даже в статье на MSDN было написано (пруфы утеряны, к сожалению).

Comment: Отсутствие причин не использовать и должность наличия - разные вещи. Не находите?